# Dose Laplace distribution satisfy Paley-Wiener theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-distributions, fourier-analysis

I recently learned about Paley-Wiener theorem and I have a question. I would really appreciate if you could help me!

Consider ${\bf Laplace}(0,1/A)$ in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution).
Its probability density function is
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac{A}{2}\exp{(-A|x|)}
\end{equation}
$f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and for any positive real number $B$,
$f(x)\leq\frac{A}{2}\exp{(B|x|)}$ holds.

Therefore, I think its Fourier transform $F(t)$ should vanish outside an interval $[−B,B]$ by [Paley-Wiener theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem).
But $F(t)=\frac{A^2}{A^2+t^2}$ dose not vanish.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from your link to the [Paley-Wiener theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem) (emphasis is my own)

> An **entire function** $F$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$ is the Fourier–Laplace transform of a distribution $v$ of compact support if and only if [...]

$f$ isn't entire in $\mathbb{C}$. That would require it to be complex-differentiable at every point of the plane. But $f$ isn't even real-differentiable at $x = 0$.

Comment: Oh, I missed it. Thank you. I understand about Laplace distribution. However, Gaussian distribution is differentiable and its Fourier transform doesn't vanish either. What about Gaussian?